# Drivers required for Mac Mini 2014 (A1347) for Windows 10 to run properly

Tags: windows-10, drivers, boot-camp, mac-mini

I've decided to dedicate my complete Mac Mini A1347 to Windows 10 as it is not compatibble with the current MacOS. So I've cleaned its SSD and installed Windows 10 only from the USB installation media.

I've tried to install the BootCamp 6.0.6136, it installs all necessary drivers.

But I actually don't want to install the complete BootCamp set on Windows because I'm not sure it would install only required drivers.

Windows 10 shows 4 devices without drivers after clean install: Wi-Fi, Intel Management, some PCI device and Bluetooth. First three are easily upgraded with drivers manually.

But I can not catch what Bluetooth driver is required. Neither Broadcom's nor Atheros's (I'm not actually sure Atheros is a Bluetooth one) work.

Can you please also recommend other drivers required for my Mac Mini to run Windows 10 properly? I've currently installed Intel HDG, Apple remote and SD card. But it may be not enough.

Thank you!

Comment: See if the answers in [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6812673) are helpful.

Comment: I've tried that driver already, Windows doesn't recognize it as a compatible one.

The problem is BootCamp installs all necessary drivers, so my 6.0.6136 set already has it. I just want to avoid installing all the drivers for all Macs supported by BootCamp.